# send to hidden input value another visible text input in the same form in php

Tags: php, forms, hidden-field

Is there a simple way to send to a hidden input value the value from another visible text input value in one single form? The action on my click would use different references names depending on the source of action. See my example:

```
<form id="floatleft" method="post">
    <label for="name">My Name:</label> 
    <input name="senderName" type="text" value="">
    <input name="first_name" type="hidden" value="">
    <input alt="P" name="submit" type="image" src="https://p.gif" value="P" onclick="this.form.action='https://p.html'" />
    <input alt="z" name="submit" type="image" src="https://www.z.png" value="z" onclick="this.form.action='https://www.z.com/';" />
```

Comment: Using JS you can update hidden input value whenever visible input updated..

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you are trying to do this with? **Edit your question, dont put it in a comment**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you can do it with jQuery `change` function or `keyup` function

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
```

JS (Change function)

The change event occurs when the value of an element has been changed, so with change function, once the value inside `senderName` input changed its value (or updated value) copied to the `first_name` input. [More Detail Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#senderName').change(function() {
        $('#first_name').val($('#senderName').val());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle with Change Function](http://jsfiddle.net/jey029w1/1/)

JS (Keyup function)

With keyup function, once stop typing the value of `senderName` input will be copied to the `first_name` input. [More Detail Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#senderName').keyup(function(){
        $('#first_name').val($('#senderName').val());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle with keyup function](http://jsfiddle.net/jey029w1/2/)

Comment: Sorry for my beginner question but where in my page should I place this JS function?

Comment: anywhere below jQuery library, it's DOM ready (Note: jQuery library always comes first)

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to comment that I am using php for this form. Any change? I need to learn to understand your code. Anyway I appreciate your help.

Comment: can you put the php example here so to have a look at it,

Comment: also updated the answer with detail and references where you can find more detail about the code

Comment: Shehary, I chaged my html page to php and I am calling a function to a real php function where I placed my shopping cart function and a form to allow my customers to place personal information. Now i`d like to use this information form to be used by two different paygates deppending on customer will.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#name").on('change',function() {
 
  $("#hiddenName").val($( "#name").val());
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" type="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddeName" id="hiddenName" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```